# Joomla 3.4 PHP basic:About JTable::getInstance in libraries/joomla/table/table.php file

Tags: php, joomla

I was trying to read and understand some joomla core PHP code when I came across this function. It is located in `libraries/joomla/table/table.php` line 268. At the end of the function in line 305, it returns an object created by `$tableClass`, what I don't understand is, where is this `$tableClass` class defined? Following is a complete list of the function:

```
public static function getInstance($type, $prefix = 'JTable', $config = array())
{
    // Sanitize and prepare the table class name.
    $type       = preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9_\.-]/i', '', $type);
    $tableClass = $prefix . ucfirst($type);

    // Only try to load the class if it doesn't already exist.
    if (!class_exists($tableClass))
    {
        // Search for the class file in the JTable include paths.
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.path');

        $paths = self::addIncludePath();
        $pathIndex = 0;

        while (!class_exists($tableClass) && $pathIndex < count($paths))
        {
            if ($tryThis = JPath::find($paths[$pathIndex++], strtolower($type) . '.php'))
            {
                // Import the class file.
                include_once $tryThis;
            }
        }

        if (!class_exists($tableClass))
        {
            // If we were unable to find the class file in the JTable include paths, raise a warning and return false.
            JLog::add(JText::sprintf('JLIB_DATABASE_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_FILE_NOT_FOUND', $type), JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');

            return false;
        }
    }

    // If a database object was passed in the configuration array use it, otherwise get the global one from JFactory.
    $db = isset($config['dbo']) ? $config['dbo'] : JFactory::getDbo();

    // Instantiate a new table class and return it.
    return new $tableClass($db);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find JTable classes in tables subfolder in administration part of any component. Each file contain table class which extends from JTable class. You don't have override this method getInstance.
In fact JTable can be very simple. Some example:

```
class XXXTableCity extends JTable
{
    /**
    * Constructor
    *
    * @param object Database connector object
    */
    function __construct( &$db ) {
        parent::__construct('#__xxx_cities', 'id', $db);
    }
}
```